# NodeJS parse process.stdout to a variable

Tags: node.js, stream

I am trying to read from stdout and put it to a variable in NodeJS. This is what I've tried:

```
process.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString())
});

console.log('hello')
```

I expect it to output hello two times, but it only outputs it one time. Why is the callback not triggered? It works when using stdin..

Comment: Why would you ever want to read the text outputted by yourself? Are you trying to read the stdout of some other program?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are trying to use [the Readable Stream API](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) on [a Writable Stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable).  Specifically, [the `process.stdout` stream is for writing to stdout not reading from stdout](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout).  What you are trying to do isn't possible, would create an infinite loop if it did work, and [breaks the definition of what stdin and stdout are](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).

Comment: +1. This is the most logical description of the problem in the question itself in the thread.

Answer (score 4):

A less confusing version of the above would be:

```
process.stdout._orig_write = process.stdout.write;
process.stdout.write = (data) => {
  mylogger.write(data);
  process.stdout._orig_write(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!

If someone encounters the `Max call stack` error, probably, it is because the variable is assigned twice. So, you need to add the condition check to make sure that the `_orig_write` property doesn't exist:
`if (!process.stdout._orig_write) process.stdout._orig_write = process.stdout.write;`

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it. Read [@mattr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26720537/4510033).

Instead, you can hook into the `process.stdout.write` and **get all the text printed to `process.stdout`**. I'm using the code below with my Node.js server.

```
global.serverLog = "";
process.stdout.write = (function(write) {
        return function(string, encoding, fileDescriptor) {
                global.serverLog += string;
                write.apply(process.stdout, arguments);
            };
    })(process.stdout.write);
```

Note that you can do the same thing to `process.stderr`, too.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest the following:

1. Pipe stdout from the process to a duplexstream where you can create a readstream
2. You parse the data, and then you can close it.

Comment: How do you do this exactly? Got an example?

Comment: AFAIU, you can't pipe stdout to another stream as it is not a readable stream